# Testing that function exits a program if requests.ConnectionError occurs

Tags: python, api, unit-testing, python-requests

I have a function that makes a request, I need it to terminate the program if there is a Connection Error:

```
def apiRequest(uri):
    try:
        response = requests.get(uri)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        sys.exit(1)
```

My test is this:

```
   class apiTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_httpRequest(self):
         with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
             ApiTest.httpRequest('http://rdog-api.kinduff.com/hello')
         self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

This runs but doesnt actually do anything. Any advice for getting this working?

Comment: You missed part where two code samples related one to another. In first you define function `apiRequest()`, in second you call method `ApiTest.httpRequest` in another method of `apiTest` class (not even `ApiTest`).

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't actually do anything"? Assuming you are actually calling the code, "nothing" means both assertions passed.